# D3.js enter() broken for svg shape animation but updates and removes them fine

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Building off of Malcom McLean's "D3 Tips and Tricks" [update data dynamically](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-update-data-dynamically---on-click) and [scatterplot](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-change-a-line-chart-into-a-scatter-plot) tutorials, I'm trying to take two different csv's of data, and through animation, plot points for each when selected (using two html buttons).

When the user hits either button, my changeTask function moves the line, axises, and points accordingly, as well as removes any extra points that are not in the new dataset.

However, new points are not added (e.g. when the new data should have more points than the current one). Something is wrong with the .enter() in the changeTask function. If you try my code and data, you'll notice that points on the left are missing when hitting reset.

Full code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
.area {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
    stroke-width: 0;
}
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 60px;                    
    height: 28px;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton" 
           type="button" 
           value="Update" 
           onclick="changeData('update')" 
    />
    <input name="resetButton" 
           type="button" 
           value="Reset" 
           onclick="changeData('reset')" 
    />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %B");

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

/* // define the area below the line
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); }); */

// define the first line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

// create the canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
            );

// find x-axis start point
function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
}

// find y-axis start point
function make_y_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
}

original_data = "data2.csv"

// get and plot the data
d3.csv(original_data, function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });
    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
    // create the line
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
    // dot the points
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
    // give the graph an x axis
    svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", height + margin.bottom)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");
    // create the Y axis
    svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Value");
    // give the graph a title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")
        .text("Value vs Date Graph")
    // create vertical tick marks
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )
    // make horizontal tick marks
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )
}); 

// animation that changes the graph's data
function changeData(task) {

    // determine which dataset to use depending on purpose
    if (task == "update") {
        file = "scatterplot_update.csv";
    } else if (task == "reset") {
        file = original_data;
    }

    // Get the data again
    d3.csv(file, function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

        // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
        var svg = d3.select("body")
        var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)

        // Make the changes
        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        // update existing circles
        circle.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); });
        // enter new circles
        circle.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); });
        // remove old circles
        circle.exit().remove()

    });
}

</script>
</body>
```

The data sets are:

**data2.csv**:

```
date,close
1-May-12,58.13
30-Apr-12,53.98
27-Apr-12,67
26-Apr-12,89.7
25-Apr-12,99
24-Apr-12,130.28
23-Apr-12,166.7
20-Apr-12,234.98
19-Apr-12,345.44
18-Apr-12,443.34
17-Apr-12,543.7
16-Apr-12,580.13
13-Apr-12,605.23
12-Apr-12,622.77
11-Apr-12,626.2
10-Apr-12,628.44
9-Apr-12,636.23
5-Apr-12,633.68
4-Apr-12,624.31
3-Apr-12,629.32
2-Apr-12,618.63
30-Mar-12,599.55
29-Mar-12,609.86
28-Mar-12,617.62
27-Mar-12,614.48
26-Mar-12,606.98
```

**scatterplot_update.csv:**

```
date,close
10-May-12,99.55
8-May-12,0
6-May-12,67.62
4-May-12,64.48
2-May-12,60.98
1-May-12,58.13
30-Apr-12,53.98
27-Apr-12,67
26-Apr-12,89.7
25-Apr-12,99
24-Apr-12,90.28
23-Apr-12,106.7
20-Apr-12,94.98
19-Apr-12,85.44
18-Apr-12,73.34
17-Apr-12,53.7
16-Apr-12,50.13
13-Apr-12,65.23
12-Apr-12,62.77
11-Apr-12,66.2
10-Apr-12,68.44
9-Apr-12,66.23
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: For troubleshooting, it is easiest if you share a working example of your problem.  For example, using jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/).

Comment: Hi Josh, great point thanks. For jsfiddle, do I have to move the data off of csv's into the code? I don't see any place to upload the data into jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using the data function without providing a key function, D3 is simply joining the data to circles with the corresponding index... and since your second dataset is smaller, there are no new circles entering the scene.

To fix this, just add the following second parameter to both of your data function calls:

```
...
.data(data, function(d) {return d.date;})
```

which will let D3 use each datum's date field as a join key.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks so much for responding. I added the parameter to both data function calls, but as a result, only points that have the same x coordinate (date) in both data sets are preserved. Something's still missing...

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! I used Google Chrome's handy Webkit Inspector to see what was wrong. Inside my changeData function, my svg selector is missing the .select("svg").select("g") -- so of course, the points were not being placed where they should be!

The correct var assignments in the changeData function are:

```
// Select the section we want to apply our changes to 
var svg = d3.select("body").select("svg").select("g");
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
```